# Laravel Dusk login testing

Tags: laravel, authentication, testing

I copied the code:

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
    'email' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
    ]);

    $this->browse(function ($browser) use ($user) {
    $browser->visit('/login')
        ->type('email', $user->email)
        ->type('password', 'password')
        ->press('Login')
        ->assertPathIs('/home');
});
}
```

Source: laravel.com/docs/6.0/dusk

And all the time I get the error:

```
1) Tests \ Browser \ LoginTest :: testBasicExample
Actual path [/ login] does not equal expected path [/ home].
Failed asserting that '/ login' matches PCRE pattern "/ ^ \ / home $ / u".
```

web.php

```
Route :: get ('/', function () {
    return view ('welcome');
});
Route :: post ('/ user', 'UserController @ store');
Auth :: routes ();
Route :: get ('/ home', 'HomeController @ index') -> name ('home');
```

In phpunit.xml I added:

```
<env name = "DB_CONNECTION" value = "sqlite" />
<env name = "DB_DATABASE" value = ": memory:" />
```

What could be the reason for the error?

Comment: Hello, could you please explain a bit more what you are trying to do?

Comment: I installed Laravel 6.
I installed Duck.
I installed Laravel auth.

Everything on standard settings.

And when I wanted to test the login options using Duck, I get the error I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because the redirect didn't happen. Because there was no user with the given details.

When Dusk test is failing, there would be a screenshot for you in the **tests/Browser/screenshots/** directory.
Have a look on the screenshot and you will solve the problem